# wordpress, get_posts that match a query with meta only

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've an meta field named "date"(custom field), now I'm trying to get all the posts that hasn't passed today's date, until now I did it with

```
if( strtotime(date("d.m.Y",strtotime(get_field("date", $post->id)))) < strtotime(date("d.m.Y")) ) { }
```

but it affected the pagination 2, so I need to change the `get_posts()` function to return the relevant results, but I'm not sure how to do it the doc talks about fetching the values with a match meta field value(which isn't exactly the case)

Comment: What's "pagination 2"? Do you mean that it affects certain pages (here, the second one) of your system? If so we would also need to understand how this system works (and why page 2 is specifically broken).

Comment: You better use wp_query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @Kyll, "it affects the pagination" .. thats it.. I just need it as part of the query so it will solve eveything

Comment: @MohammadArshi, but how can I use the query with a custom field(meta)

Comment: its working like `'meta_key=keyname'` and I need the result of meta field that is after the todays date

Comment: $args = array(
 'meta_key'     => 'custom_field',
 'meta_value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
 'meta_compare' => '>=',
 'post_type'    => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Well, I tried like your examples `  $args = array( 
  'meta_key'   => 'date', 
  'meta_value'  => date('Ymd'), // as this is the way it gets saved in the db.
  'meta_compare'  => '<',
  'post_type'  => 'event',
  'lang'         => getLang(),
 ); 
 $mypages1 = new WP_Query( $args ); ` but it doesn't show anything ... I tried everything even using `strtotime` on the meta_value but I didn't know to to do it on the current item ..